# Python3.6 How to setup a connection with SQLAlchemy to SQL Lite Studio?

Tags: windows, sqlite, flask, sqlalchemy, python-3.6

I have a Problem i am working on my own Falsk Website and i am currently on the point of creating a Database to login and i want to Use SQL lite Studio [It Looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EGGRA.png) 3.1.1 (Beacuse i can't install mysql ...) !

My Python Flask code Looks like this :

```
from flask import Flask , request , render_template
import os ,sys
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = "THATS THE THING I DONT KNOW"

db = SQLAlchemy(app)

...
if __name__ == "__main__":
app.run(
    host=app.config.get('HOST'),
    port=8080,
    threaded=True ,ssl_context=('cert.pem',"key.pem"))
```

It works like a charm but i can't connect to the database because i dont know what to put here : `app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = "THATS THE THING I DONT KNOW"`

I allredy created this file for my Databse by my Self [HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/flYnb.png)

and Connected it to the SQL Lite Studio like this : [HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6hVLh.png)

But i Dont know if this is right and the Bigger question is how can i connect to it using SQLAlchemy ?

Thanks for your help and sorry for the bad english

EDIT : after i added 
`sqlite:///C:\\Path\\DATA.db`
to my scrip it dose work
i also added this code :

```
class Users(db.Model):
id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
Email = db.Column(db.String(200))
Username = db.Column(db.String(200))
Pwd = db.Column(db.String(200))
```

it did work and it created a Table
in the commandline :

```
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
from main import db
db.create_all()
exit()
```

and then proceeded like this :

```
sqlite3
SQLite version 3.22.0 2018-01-22 18:45:57
Enter ".help" for usage hints.
Connected to a transient in-memory database.
Use ".open FILENAME" to reopen on a persistent database.
sqlite> .open DATA.db
sqlite> .tables
Users
```

and i also added this to the python script:

```
@app.route("/login",methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    if request.method == "POST":
    email = request.values.get('email_addr')
    password = request.values.get('pwd')
    print(email,password)

    Email = Users(Email=email,Pwd=password)
    db.session.add(Email)
    db.session.commit()
```

So thanks for the help i fixed it and i was aperrently to stupid to see the big DATA box in the Graphicel interface .

PS : i am Using python3.6 and Windows 10

Comment: Sorry for the typos

Comment: for windows this will be like: `sqlite:///C:\\path\\to\\data.db` http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/engines.html#sqlite

Comment: I did that but i don't know how to now create tabels an add them with my python Script

Comment: sounds like you have a new question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve there are countless examples/tutorials online of using these tools

Comment: i fixed it thaks abigperson :D